A limit related to Poisson kernel in unit disc
I am trying to show
$$\lim_{r\to1^-}\int_0^{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}\right)d\theta=+\infty.$$
An approach is to apply the theory of Hardy space. Indeed, the function $g(z)=\exp\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$ defined on the unit disc $\mathbb D$ does not lie in the Hardy space $H^p(\mathbb D)$ for any $p$ since (see Theorem 4.1 in Chap. II of "Bounded analytic function" written by John Garnett)
$$\log|g(0)|=1>\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|g(e^{i\theta})|d\theta.$$
My question is that how could we show this limit by direct estimation. I can understand that this limit goes to infinity from the graph of the Poisson kernel (as $r$ goes to 1, the mass of Poisson kernel is concentrated at the neighborhood of $0$). But how could I show this strictly?

Is the limit from above or below?

It is from below.
